# Purtest Object - How to save Output as tex file?

Tags: r, latex, stargazer, plm

I was wondering whether there is a way to save a `purtest` - output as a `LaTeX`
file?

As you can see in the example-code, I have already tried to produce it via stargazer. However, the `stargazer` function does not support the `purtest-class`.

```
library(plm)
library(stargazer)

dat <- data.frame(entity = c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)),year = 
rep(1970:1979,2),value = rnorm(20))
pdat <- pdata.frame(dat,index = c("entity","year"))

res <- purtest(object = pdat$value,test = "ips",exo = "intercept",pmax = 1)

stargazer(summary(res),type = "latex")
```

I know that it is possible to extract values manually, to store them in a data.frame and eventually to save the data.frame via `print.xtable` as a `LaTeX` file.
But perhaps there is any neat solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stargazer library has a lot of checks constraining the classes that can be used. 
Class "purtest" is not included, but as Stargazer support exporting of "matrix" class, one can trick the restrictions. For example:

```
    # the problem
    library(plm)
    library(stargazer)

    dat <- data.frame(entity = c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)),year = 
                        rep(1970:1979,2),value = rnorm(20))
    pdat <- pdata.frame(dat,index = c("entity","year"))

    res <- purtest(object = pdat$value,test = "ips",exo = "intercept",pmax = 1)


    # One solution: extract the parametars and place them in the matrix:
    a = unlist(res$idres[[1]])
    b = unlist(res$idres[[2]])
    all =  rbind(a, b)
    class(all) <- c("matrix")

    stargazer(all,type = "latex",align = T) 
    # need to align , else you get strange double dollar signs
```